# Alternative war attacking strategy for TH7

Tags: clash-of-clans

I'm currently using the all-Dragon strategy which is an 80% guarantee for 2-3 stars. However, sometimes the loot isn't equal (or less than) to what I've spent.

10 Lv 2 Drag = 300 000 Elixir. Still without spells. + Barbarian King(1) + Clan Army.

I want to know other efficient strategies without consuming much resources.

Currently, I have

- Level 4: Barb, Arc, Giant,
- Level 3: WB, Goblin, Balloons, Wiz, Lv 2 Drag,
- Level 1 Healer,

While my spells are Level 4, 3, and 2 respectively. I've also unlocked Hog Rider and Minions, both Level 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Mass Dragons + Rage Spells is one of the most effective strategies for getting stars around TH7/8, in my opinion.  It's generally pretty easy to deploy as well.

That said, as you've noted it's very resource intensive.  The thing is, Clan Wars aren't really great for elixir gains.  You're much better off with collector raids with [BARCH](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-tricks-rapid-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) to get elixir, and even gold for that matter.  Clan Wars are really mostly good for getting the Dark Elixir bonuses.

There are a couple of alternative strategies, though, that you might consider.

One is [Giant/Healer](http://www.withoutthesarcasm.com/tips-raiding-around-town-hall-7-clash-clans/) which is basically just a swarm of Giants, with a few Wall Breakers to speed up the process, and 1 or 2 Healers and Heal spells to back them up.  The problem with this is speed - Giants are slow.  You might have the base dead to rights and run out of time - especially when factoring in the time it takes to lure the Clan Castle.  Also the Healers are air and the Giants won't tank air defenses for them.

Another is [Dragons + Balloons](http://forum.withoutthesarcasm.com/discussion/2/my-balloon-dragon-clan-war-strategy).  Balloons are somewhat cheaper and they target defenses.  The Dragons can drop first and tank for the Balloons, which makes them a bit more likely to hit air defenses before they get taken out.  This strategy works best when the AD's are close to the outside of the base, and you can blitz them quickly.

DE troops at TH7 are both weak and costly, so I don't suggest using them.

Another important factor to consider when choosing a war raid troop composition is **what troops and spells have you upgraded?**  Ideally you want to max out your troops before you use them in clan wars.  Even with the best strategy and perfect troop mix, if your troops are underleveled the attack will go to waste.

Answer (score 3):

This is a link for a th7 balloonion attack that I use quite often. It's cheaper than dragons and in my opinion more fun to execute due to the fact that you actually have to use strategy and have to focus unlike dragons + 3 lightning spells. It's a guaranteed 3 star 95% of the time.

Just make sure to place rage spells in correct positions and to lure (a drag in the cc without luring is a nightmare and will guarantee you a 0%-20% attack turnout). Good luck!

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=WO-DUF4nd_E&index=1&list=FLFutG8zfZEMmbvt8Ie1OVtw
 guarantee you a 0%-20% attack turnout).

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to town hall 7's a attack strategy I use. I use 10 giants, 50 archers, 50 barbarians and 50 Goblins. I don't have a name for it but this is how you use it:

You need to check for clan castle troops so place a barbarian. Draw it out to a defense and put 2 or 3 lightning spells so it takes out both the troops and the defense. Then Place the giants as tanks and barbarians as support and archers as more support and the goblins doing their job.

I used to always get 6 stars in clan was when I was Town Hall 7. Now I do GoWiPe or GoWiWi because I'm a TH10.

Comment: Its Also One Of The Cheapest Attack Strategies. Costs Around 20,000 to 30,000 discluding the spells because sometimes you dont even need spells.

Comment: are you really masterov? good to see you here

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a strategy that I call '888', as it uses:

- 8 level 2 dragons
- 8 level 4 wizards
- 8 archers
- Barbarian King.

I take a dragon or level 6 Wizard in my cc. I use the archers to take the cc troops out and I kill them using archers and 2 wizards.

I then proceed to destroy the ad using 3 lightning spells, and deploy dragons and wizards near the other ad.

I got 3 stars on every 7th bases and on 8th bases as well. It is also cost effective as it costs only 240000 (dragons) + 1280  (archers) +  24000  (wizards) + 60000 ( Lightning spells) which is 325800 elixir.

Trust me, this is an excellent strategy.

Answer (score 1):

Mass dragons are awesome for clan wars - but if we want to profit from the win, an alternative is a must.

I use:

- 14 Giants,
- 1 Healer,
- 13 Wizards,
- 2 Wall Breakers,
- 2 Dragons,
- 1 Barbarian king,
- 3 Lightning spells, and
- 1 CC Dragon

in my first attack. This gives me a 2 stars most of the time but with perfect execution, a 3 star is achievable. And the attack costs only around 180,000 Elixir.

Answer (score 1):

If u have 150+ space in your army camp this is a good attack strategy.

- Goblins
- Barbarians
- Archers
- Giants
- Wall Breakers

When you attack you must only have 30 and under Archers. Also any spell combination goes with this attack it is call the BWAG BWEAKER 
You might can find me in some clans than say hi.

Answer (score 0):

I've found the most consistent attack strategy for town hall 7 is dragaloonian (in wars, I have a 100% 3 star success rate for any TH7 after 10 attacks).

I use 25 lvl 4 balloons, 3 dragons (lvl not important), 5 minions, 1 giant and lvl 6 balloons in CC.

The giant lures out the cc. I then bring the cc to a corner with a minion. If you can, try to drag the cc troops over an AD and drop 3 lightning spells to take it out, if not, once the cc is in a corner, drop 3 dragons. I then drop my 25 balloons so they are spread out along half the base closest to the remaining AD (balloons are dropped in an L shape surrounding that AD). I then drop my CC containing lvl 6 balloons in the shortest path to the remaining AD. the remaining minions are dropped on any other corner structures and the barb king is dropped about 30 sec behind the balloons for clean up.

This strategy works with ALL Town Hall 7s and some weak Town Hall 8s

Answer (score 0):

The strategy I use most at th7 was definitely the giant healer strategy.  I usually go with 16-18 giants, two healers, 2-5 wall breakers and ard 18-20 wizards. I mix them ard a lil bit depending on opponents bases I find in war...  I have been getting 6 stars in war using this strategy and I sometimes even get two stars when attacking mid th8s.I also go with two heal and one rage (heal for giants/wizards that are out of healing range fron healers) the rage is for speeding up the giants while they tank the dmg and let the wizards clear up. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

### Battle Composition:

- 12 Level. 4 Wizards
- 10 Level. 4 Healers
- 1 Heal Spell
- 2 Rage Spells

Using your Clan Castle, drop and drag near a Air Defense and at once drop all of your wizards at a spot far from the range of the mortar and put the healers and Barbarian King at the same Distance. The wizards are sure to clear it out in less than 2 minutes.

Comment: Can you write this in a way it is more readable?

Comment: Perhaps in English. That would be nice.

Comment: I tried my best.

Comment: How would you suggest a TH7 base acquire 10 level 4 healers (angels)? They can only be upgraded to level 2 at TH7 and level 3 at TH8.

Comment: @Timelord The edit was valid, healer is the correct name of the unit in the game

Answer (score 0):

A great town hall 7 attack I recommend if you're fighting for DE is 3 healers and as many wizards as you can get.  This strategy is expense so I recommend gathering up some elixr.  The cost will be around 150,000-195,000.
Also, go for the air defenses first.

Answer (score 0):

All out dragon attack is best but expensive so using wizards giants and healers with around 10 hogs will be useful as the hogs break down defense easily then put down giants with one healer and wizards with one healer so they work in contrast

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a loonion attack with 30 archers 20 minions and 26 balloons with two heals and one rage+ barb king. First you lure the clan troops out with an archer then lure to corner and then kill the cc troops and spread the balloons and drop your cc troops (recommend 4 level 6 balloons) behind the air sweeper nearest to an air defense and drop a heal on the air defense and a rage and heal on the second air defense. Have fun using this attack

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend a giwi attack with 16 giants, 30 archers and 28 wizards plus barb king and wall breakers and two heals one rage, drop one archer to lure cc troops and kill in corner then spread out giants just in case there are giant bombs there and drop three wall breakers depending on wall level then drop heal on mortars and area with walls and then drop a rage with the area with wizards so they destroy everything

Answer (score 0):

This works for a lot of bases for me. I've used it successfully against Th7, Th8 and even some Th9s and Th10's.

- 19 lvl 4 wiz
- 6 lvl 1 drags
- 2 lvl 4 barbs
- 2 lvl 4 archers

Answer (score 0):

My most effective strategy included all max level archers and barbarian king with rage spells, lightning spells, and a few healing spells and healers. I use lightning to target or weaken powerful defenses then deploy (in order) archers healers and have barb king flank the other end. Then I play some rage spell and healing spells. Then I play clan troops which I usually only ask for goblins for that extra loot.

Answer (score 0):

I use 15 giants, some wizards, archers, wall breakers, and barbarians. Use two heal spells and one rage. This in my opinion is just about as good as all drags because it doesn't madder how good their air defense is.

First, draw out the cc troops with the barbs and take them out with the barbs and archers.

Drop down one or two giants to check for traps.

Then drop down the rest of the giants and the wall breakers.

Stack a heal and rage spell on the giants and use the second heal spell when you think your giants need it.

Drop your wizards behind the giants so they don't take much damage.

This usually gets 3 star on weak to semi good town hall 7's. It gets 2 stars on stronger town hall 7's and low town hall 8's.

Answer (score 0):

Dragalloonion

Use 3 dragons 16 balloons and 20 minions 
I have always gotten 2 stars with this attack
It has been successful all the time from attacking the bottom left and top right.

Answer (score 0):

I call this strategy ballon-rider and it is like this:

- 10 hogs
- 25 balloons
- 25 archers
- 1 rage spell
- 2 healing spells

It works when one air defense is slightly outside from the center.
Release the hogs near the outside air defense, then send the balloons in mass from the other side. If the air bombs appear then drop the healing spell on balloons and drop the rage spell when all balloons are on one place, use the other healing spell when necessary.

This strategy works for town hall 7.

Comment: .....Too many exceptions......

Answer (score 0):

The best for me is using 
12 giants 
8 wall breakers 
60 barbarians
60 archers 
2 minnions
2 rage spells
1 heal spell
1 barb king 
Any type of cc troops other than goblins and barbarians and healers. 
Although this cost 200 space for training.  it is reliable for getting dark elixer and loot. It is short and cheap.

Answer (score -1):

Mass Dragon Attack at Town Hall 7 = 99% of 3 stars. Brings 3 Lightning spells, take down a Air defense then drag Dragons in a line!

You can see more at: http://cocland.com/strategies/advanced-dragon-attack-strategy

Answer (score -1):

I use a army which consists of:

- 25 balloons
- 5 wizz
- 55 archers
- King
- 2 heal spells
- 1 rage spell

You can just spread your balloons and deploy a heal or rage right at wizz towers and/or all air defenses. When 1 side of defenses are cleared then deploy arc and wizz and watch them destroying the whole village and at same time deploy your king.

It ensures u 2 or 3 stars on every attack.

Answer (score -1):

Hog riders 30 hog riders and 50 archers clan castle with archer or drag 3 star th7 and th 8 95 percent bit costly on the DE side but I get 6 stars a raid my clan is lucky to pull 3

Comment: Can you add details about what makes this strategy strong?

Comment: This sounds expensive and ineffective to me. Level 1 hog riders are expensive to make and get destroyed pretty easily. Upgrading them to level 2 at TH7 is extremely expensive (20k dark elixir, which is the max a TH7 base can store) and not something I'd recommend any TH7 player to do.

Answer (score -1):

This is what I use for my attacking strategy:

- 80 barbarians
- 60 archers
- 20 minions
- 3 healing spells

It is cheap and reliable. It has not failed me yet.

Answer (score -2):

The best combination is

- 7 drags
- 3 lightnings
- 11 wiz
- 11 archers
- barb king
- cc drag (I suggest lvl 3 or 4)

You want to kill cc troops - lightning on 1 AD and then all drags near the second AD. In last drop your barb king and wiz arch to clear remaining buildings (timer doesn't let drags to 3 star usually) So **cleaning troops are very important**